# Native HTML5 drag and drop not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11

I have used javascript code to drag and drop between my divs.
Native HTML5 drag and drop.
This code works fine in chrome and firefox but it is not working IE11
Nothing is shown in console too
I am unable to find the problem

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 [draggable] {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    .box {
      height: 125px;
      width: 125px;
      float: left;
      border: 3px solid #0092BF;
      background-color: #FFEBDD;
      margin-right: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: move;
    }
    .box header {
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: #000 0 1px;
      box-shadow: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                                   color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)),
                                   color-stop(0.50, rgb(79,79,79)),
                                   color-stop(1, rgb(21,21,21)));
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    </style>

<body>
  <div id="boxes-example">
        <div class="box" draggable="true">
            <header>A</header>
            <p>
            order!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" draggable="true">
            <header>B</header>
            <p>
            Put me
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" draggable="true">
            <header>C</header>
            <p>
            right
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" draggable="true">
            <header>D</header>
            <p>
            into
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" draggable="true">
            <header>E</header>
            <p>
            the
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script for drag and drop:

```
 <script>
        (function () {
            var id_ = 'boxes-example';
            var boxes_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .box');
            var dragSrcEl_ = null;

            this.handleDragStart = function (e) {
                e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);

                dragSrcEl_ = this;

                this.style.opacity = '0.5';

                // this/e.target is the source node.
                this.addClassName('moving');
            };

            this.handleDragOver = function (e) {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
                }

                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

                return false;
            };

            this.handleDragEnter = function (e) {
                this.addClassName('over');
            };

            this.handleDragLeave = function (e) {
                // this/e.target is previous target element.

                this.removeClassName('over');
            };

            this.handleDrop = function (e) {
                // this/e.target is current target element.

                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
                }

                // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same box we're dragging.
                if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
                    dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
                }

                return false;
            };

            this.handleDragEnd = function (e) {
                // this/e.target is the source node.
                this.style.opacity = '1';

                [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
                    box.removeClassName('over');
                    box.removeClassName('moving');
                });
            };

            [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
                box.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable boxes to be draggable.
                box.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
                box.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
                box.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
                box.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
                box.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
                box.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
            });
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly in IE11 (11.0.9600.17801) for me. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4t54c3m/

Comment: not working for me @Daniel

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Using IE11, I can reorder the boxes just like in Chrome!

Comment: it works when I create a fiddle...but when i directly run that code in IE I am able to drag @Daniel

Comment: nakshatra5 is right I have the same results of the test of @Daniel's jsfiddle, i.e: I have the same problem

Comment: Are you guys using prototype? I don't another js framework that uses addClassName method to a node besides the Prototype javascript framewok

Answer (score 1):

First you're using `'addClassName'` which AFAIK is available via [Prototype.js](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addClassName/) (do not confuse it with Jquery's `addClass()` which does the same thing)

So you need for it to include `prototype.js`  or use another library with another syntax
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script`>
This is enough in order to make your script runs without errors

To make the drag and drop work you need to add `preventDefault()` in each of the `dragenter` and `drop` events handlers :

```
      this.handleDragEnter = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.addClassName('over');
    };

        this.handleDrop = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                   ..............
                   .......
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking for a solution that works in IE11 as well, Here is a good article which explains it. [Drag and Drop File Uploading](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/)